# Textview Widget Mono

Tags: mono

I started to program with monodevelop (gtk#).

I have a very simple question:

```
protected void OnButton1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textview1.Buffer.Text="hallooo";

}
```

I just want the textview widget to show the text above. But when I run the program nothing happens.
You need more code?

Comment: It is very likely that you set the text to a wrong object. Read GTK/GTK# documentation or check existing samples.

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand. How do I set the text to a right object? I read the documentation but i don't really understand.

Comment: Ok, I found a example: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T:Gtk.TextView#

Comment: I tried to put the code block in a buttonClickEvent:

Comment: but nothing happens when i click the button.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question. I'm a noob and just started with c# and mono. Does anyone know how to use the source code with a button click event?